# kendo ui template error when using german characters

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, runtime-error

I'm using a globalized Kendo template in which I globalize the title of the button:

```
      -bunch of redundant code deleted-

  class="btn-ico del" title="@Resources.AdminResources.DeleteStr">
```

This works fine in English, Italian, Japanese and Polish however in German the word for delete happens to have an umlaut (Löschen) and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'
```

This is how the browser renders it:

```
 class="btn-ico del" title="L&';246;schen"
```

By default I have

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

set in my template; changing it to the `iso-8851-1` encoding did not work.
Temporarily I changed  Löschen to Loeschen but that is not elegant.

Comment: Could you show actual template code as well as how you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo encodes the character and places a hash (#), just replace all hashes with escaped hashes

In C# I would do..   .Replace("#", "\#" )